# Which is better: use 1 glDrawElements(and transform vectors with math) or use multiple glDrawElements(and change viewproj matrix for each object)

Tags: performance, opengl, 3d, render, opentk

Using VB.Net with OpenTK.

Let's say I have a class 'cube' which encapsulates a list of position and color data for displaying a cube. It takes a Matrix4 as transformation data. I will be using multiple cubes in my program, each with different scale, rotation and translation data.

So, as far as performance is concerned, which is faster? :

- Transform the original cube vertex data for each cube and then draw them all with just one glDrawElements.
- Change the uniform matrix of my vertex shader to the transformation data of cube and then call glDrawElements for each cube.

Note that there will be animation involved so transformation data will change over time.

PS- I'm thinking of a third option: Buffer the vertex data of just 1 cube and use instancing, but I'm still a beginner and this may be difficult.

Comment: Essentially this asks whether shader's calculations are more efficient than regular math in code. Plus there are multiple calls for the second method.

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to implement both methods and see whats faster. I'm quite sure that method 1 will be faster when objects get more complex than a cube.

Answer (score 0):

It should always be faster to use a single draw call instead of multiple. Given that your desired output is the same. So 1 draw call resulting in 10 boxes should be faster than 10 draw calls each drawing 1 box.

Now considering that we're talking about a tiny box then it shouldn't be noticeable whether you used 1 or 10 draw calls. Bottom line is that it all depends on the data size, and what the goal of the outcome is. So if you have 10 models, but only at given time need to draw 4 of them, then those 4 draw calls might be cheaper than a single draw call rendering all 10 models.

However the performance starts competing if each model isn't static. So if those 10 models are all supposed to move around, then you'll probably end up having to do something funky that's equally expensive to do.

The third option could also be to use [`glDrawElementsInstanced()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElementsInstanced.xhtml). A good rule of thumb is that the fewer state changes and the fewer commands you'll be sending the GPU the better.

All in all, the easiest way to verify it, is to have a more complex model and scene and simply benchmark each solution.